# Access struct inside struct with pointers

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, compare

I have 2 structs interlinked. These forming a linked list.

```
typedef struct  {
    char *text;
    int count;
} *Item;

typedef struct node {
    Item item;
    struct node *next;
} *link;
```

I am building a lookup function to compare the Item structs.

```
link lookup(link head, Item item){
    link list;
    for(list = head; list != NULL; list = list->next)
        if(strcmp(list->item->text, item->text) == 0)
            return list;
    return NULL;
}
```

More specifically, can I do **list->item->text** on the if statement or do I have to do **(*list).(*item).text** ? Or is this not possible at all?

Comment: You are referencing a struct via a pointer, the `->` operator is correct. (however, be careful using `typedef` to pointers (e.g. `typedef struct ... *Item`), that can mask levels of indirection throughout the remainder of the code making the determination difficult at first glance). Usually better to `typedef struct ... Item` so you account for the level of indirection in your code itself. Some people like the typedef to a pointer, personally, I find it usually causes more problems than it is worth..

Comment: You are correct, except that `(*list).(*item).text` is incorrect syntax.  Instead, you would need to write `(*(*list).item).text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want, except you used the wrong syntax for the second form.  The following are equivalent:

```
list->item->text
```

and:

```
(*(*list).item).text
```

What you had, `(*list).(*item).text`, will cause a syntax error, since you must have a structure member after the `.` operator.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do `list->item->text` on the if statement?

Yes, since both are pointers.

---

Recall that `a->b` is the same as `(*a).b`.